# Problem of Regular expression double brackets

Tags: regex, parsing

I have this regular expression: `(\[.*?\])` for finding the pattern `[data1],[data2],[data3]`, and works, but I found a case where doesn't work: `[*this bracket have a other bracket[]]`

I'm trying to find a solution, if brackets contain inner brackets, an error occurs in recognition.

This is a python code

```
tags = re.findall('\[.*?\]', log_string)
```

- This is target log

> [TimeStamp: 2020-11-4 11:22:55] [Event: Break Point Hit]

=> Result : [TimeStamp: 2020-11-4 11:22:55],[Event: Break Point Hit]

> [TimeStamp: 2020-11-4 12:24:18] [Event: ds:[eax+0xFCA], cx]

=> Result : [TimeStamp: 2020-11-4 12:24:18],[Event: ds:[eax+0xFCA]
(', cs' of Event is missing)

[This is a normaly work case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avlXw.png)

[This is an error case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHnQp.png)

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Please post code snippets as plain text formatted as code rather than links to images of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the nesting depth of inner brackets is limited to 1:

```
\[(?:\[.*?]|.)*?]
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ZQC01svBSDztTs).

This works by optionally consuming the entire pattern `[...]` within the outer brackets, or just `.` if no such inner group is found.

The unnecessary grouping brackets and unnecessary escaping of `]` have been removed.

---

Or if you need to create group 1:

```
(\[(?:\[.*?]|.)*?])
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/xdUjwoofMomEbp).

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is perfect. You are an angel.